# OpenGL triangle adjacency indexing

Tags: c++, c, opengl

I am currently trying to write a program which takes a mesh as input (consisting of vertex positions and an element array) and outputs indices for use with `glDrawElements()` in `GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY` mode.

It occurred to me when trying to write the code that non-closed meshes have triangles which may not have three neighbours. For example, a mesh consisting of a single triangle has no neighbouring triangles.

[image: Triangle adjacency diagram from OpenGL 4.3 spec.]

In this case, what should the indices 2, 4 and 6 be? It seems like there should be a standard way to tell the geometry shader that one or more of the adjoining triangles do not exist. I could not find information on this in the OpenGL specification (v4.3), however.

The single triangle is a daft example, but there are plenty of meshes where not all triangles join onto three others - like a cylinder with open ends, for example.

Is there a standard way to handle cases like this? Apologies if I have missed something obvious in the spec.

*Above image copied from the OpenGL 4.3 specification.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a simple problem to solve. Generally speaking, if a GS needs adjacency information, then you're probably doing something like GS-based tessellation, where you're using adjacent vertex information to generate the new triangle data.

In cases where there is no adjacent vertex information, you need to look to your tessellation algorithm for solutions. Many algorithms have ways of dealing with cases where there is no adjacent triangle. Some tessellation algorithms *don't*; they only work on perfectly regular meshes.

In those cases, you have a problem. Edges that have no adjacent triangles are probably supposed to be sharp edges. So, if your tessellation algorithm has no way to create sharp edges, then you'll need to modify it to create such a thing.

Failing that, you can always generate phantom vertices. For example, let's say that in your diagram, there is no vertex 6. You can create data for a vertex 6 by mirroring/projecting vertex 3, through the midpoint of the line created by vertices 1 and 5. That creates the effect of a regular mesh.

Again, how good this looks depends on your tessellation algorithm and your desired results.

Answer (score 6):

After reading your comments to BЈовић, I think it is clear that what you are looking for is the primitive restart index.

You can reserve an arbitrary index value to represent primitive restart by using the following API call: `glPrimitiveRestartIndex (...)`. Often `-1` is used, as in your original question.

Take a look at: [OpenGL 4.3 Core Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec43.core.20130214.pdf) - 10.3.5 Primitive Restart - pp. 301 for more details.

I should also point out that index-based primitive restart is a feature that can be enabled / disabled, and it starts out disabled. So simply setting the restart index is not enough for it to actually do anything.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I think this is a bit different - I'm really trying to find out if there is a way to tell the geometry shader that a triangle doesn't have three neighbours. Sorry - I don't think I made it clear in the original question. I've tried to edit it a bit to make it clearer.

Comment: That is what primitive restart does. It is a simpler way of creating degenerate (zero-area) primitives than passing the same index multiple times in primitive modes that rely on connectivity (e.g. strips, adjacency, loops, etc.). Since the connectivity information in an adjacency list is not actually used for primitive assembly on its own (though you can use it for such in a custom geometry/tessellation shader), you are free to reserve any index you want to denote no adjacent primitive - reusing primitive restart simply makes the most sense.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman: If you use primitive restart on one of the adjacent indices, then the triangle will *not be processed*. Primitive restart doesn't mean "ignore this vertex". It means "start a new primitive". It takes 6 vertices to make a triangle using list-adjacency information. If you only provide 5 vertices, then the primitive will not be generated at all. Therefore, if you use restart on index 6 of an adjacency primitive, the entire triangle will disappear. This answer is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Well, if you do not provide enough vertices, then you are not going to get anything rendered. That means, if you provide less then 6 vertices for `GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY`, it will not be rendered.

The simplest test for this is to use `mode=GL_LINES` and `count=1`.

Comment: Thanks for your help - I understand that, no matter what, I have to provide 6 indices per triangle. I'm just not sure what indices to provide in the case where a triangle has no other triangle adjacent to it. How does the `GL_LINES` test work, by the way?

Comment: @Kaathe: It's just one of those things. The minimum number of points to describe a line is 2; the minimum number of points to describe a triangle is 3. While the two former cases were simple geometry, there are also restrictions imposed on the basis of how you pass your _list_ of primitives -- the minimum number of points to describe triangle adjacency is 6. If you really think about it, what purpose would you have describing triangle adjacency with only 1 triangle? Though if you are dead set on this, you can probably create 3 degenerate triangles - I do not know what you would gain from this?

Comment: @Kaathe If you have only 3 indices, you would not use `GL_TRIANGLES_ADJACENCY`. You should use `GL_TRIANGLES` instead

Comment: Sorry, the single triangle was an extreme example. But there are plenty of meshes where not every triangle has neighbouring triangles on all three sides.